# Problemas al llamar funcion desde clase con array en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando llamar una función con parámetros dentro de otra en una clase así:

```
array($this, 'functionName')
```

pero quiero saber como le paso argumentos a esta función sin ejecutarla

Comment: Realmente no termino de entender lo que estas tratando de hacer, ¿puedes desarrollar un poco mas la pregunta?  ¿los argumentos que se los quieres pasar a una función o aun método? gracias.

Comment: Estoy agregando un método con argumento a otro y la llamo de este forma [$this, 'nombreFuncion'] pero $this->nombreMetodo tiene un argumento obligatorio de esta forma $this->nombreMetodo($argumento), quiero saber como puedo llamar ese método con el argumento sin ser ejecutada en el proceso

Comment: Por el momento si quito el argumento y lo llamó de forma tradicional me funciona normal, pero intenté varias cosas con argumentos y no funciona me da error: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members

Comment: Lo que no entiendo aun es que quieres decir exactamente con `llamar ese método con el argumento sin ser ejecutada`, a que te refieres, ¿puedes añadir el contexto? es decir una clase de ejemplo con lo que que intentas hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar la función [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func-array.php) para pasarle los parámetros en ella:

Ejemplo:

```
function func($param){
    return $param;
}

$array = array(1, call_user_func_array('func',[2]));

var_dump($array);

//devuelve 
array(2) {
  [0]=>int(1)
  [1]=>int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func-array.php) para llamar a un "callable" con argumentos. Ejemplo sacado del manual:

```
class foo {
    function bar($arg, $arg2) {
        echo __METHOD__, " obtuvo $arg y $arg2\n";
    }
}
$foo = new foo;
call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("tres", "cuatro"));
// Muestra: "foo::bar obtuvo tres y cuatro"
```